# What is the best practice for using non-namespaced classes within namespaced class

Tags: php, namespaces, require, autoloader

I am creating a library using the wonderful new namespacing features that PHP has implemented in recent updates. However, I need to use the simple_html_dom.php class from within one of my classes. I'm using a standard PSR-0 compliant autoloader class, but I'm getting errors when trying to create a new object of the simple_html_dom class because of the underscores.

When looking at my autoloader class it is substituting underscores for whacks. This is easily fixed, but I'm afraid it might break my PSR-0 compliance. I was wondering what were the best practices to solve such an issue with legacy libraries.

#### Directory Structure

```
- vendor/
  - MyStuff/
    - lib/
      - simple_html_dom.php
    - MyClass1.php
```

#### MyClass1.php

```
<?php
namespace MyStuff;

// This require works
require(__DIR__ . '/lib/simple_html_dom.php');

class MyClass1 {

    public function __construct() {
         // This breaks
         // Warning: require(C:\www\vendor\LoU\simple\html\dom.php): failed to open stream
         $html = new simple_html_dom();

    }
}
```

Comment: Check (or use) the autoloader written by me. It can handle both (together). https://github.com/metashock/Jm_Autoloader/blob/master/lib/php/Jm/Autoloader.php

Comment: @hek2mgl even if the breaking class isn't namespaced and contains multiple classes?

Comment: you mean that a single file contains multiple classes? Not yet, haven't added this so far. If multiple classes are in a single file I would suggest a method like `Autoloader::registerClass($class, $file)`.. But having multiple classes in a single file is considered bad design (IMO)

Comment: yeah, it's an old library, but so far it seems to work just fine (not using autoload to include this library as shown in my example above)

Comment: Don't use simple_html_dom.. (When will it die??, when??) .. It was designed for PHP4. Now in PHP5 (since ~10years ;) there is DOMXPath. A quickfix would be to put the `require_once` on top of your autoloader class

Comment: yeah I had that, but my autoloader was still looking for a \simple\html\dom class instead of the underscored class...your autoloader fixed it if ya wanna answer I'll give you cred

Comment: will do :) .. Glad that my code helped you!!:) just for interest, can you show how you integrated my autoloader in your code so that it works now? you may post it on pastebin or even write me an email. (address can be found [here](http://www.metashock.de) ) (just short, to see. no complete, working code needed)

Comment: I simply copied your autoloader class over my old one...no magic involved

Answer (score 2):

Giving this - self advertising - answer just because you told me to do it. :)

You can use my autoloader class: [`Jm_Autoloader`](http://www.github.com/metashock/Jm_Autoloader). (you told in comments that it worked for you)

It is designed to work with `OLD_SCHOOL_CLASS_NAMES` as well as `\new\school\class\Names` and both styles mixed together.

Installation is easy using PEAR:

```
pear channel-discover metashock.de/pear
pear channel-update metashock
pear install metashock/Jm_Autoloader
```

---

On top of your main php script just add:

```
require_once 'Jm/Autoloader.php';
```

Thats it in most cases. If not, there are some options I'll not describe here as it not belongs here.

Have fun!